# Adding iAD to iphone app

Tags: ios, iad

I want add iAd to my iphone app.

Do I need to implement the programming part AND  "Enable iAd Advertising Network" in the itunes connect?

Moreover, I am experimenting that  the "fake" iAd appears on simulator but not in the real device. It is normal? Finally, Do i have a control on the frequence on the appearing og iAd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to implement the programming part

**Yes**

> AND "Enable iAd Advertising Network" in the itunes connect?

**Yes**

> Do i have a control on the frequence on the appearing og iAd?

**Yes in the developer section of the settings menu on the iOS device**

> I am experimenting that the "fake" iAd appears on simulator but not in the real device

**It appears in both the simulator and on a real device until you launch the app**